# Window is not defined in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting the error "window is not defined" in nextJS project. Here isMobile is storing the value that window size is less than 767.98 or not to execute the open/close hamburger menu functionality. This code was working fine in ReactJS but not working in NextJS. Please help me to figure out this issue.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";


const Navbar = () => {


    const isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 767.98;

    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(!isMobile);
    const toggle = () => isMobile && setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isMobile) {
          const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
            if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
              setIsMenuOpen(false);
            }
          };
        
          document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
        
          return () => {
            // Cleanup the event listener
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
          };
        }
      }, []);




    return (
        <>
            <header>

                <nav>
                    <div className="nav">

                        <div className="nav-brand">
                            <Link href="/" className="text-black"><a>Website</a></Link>
                        </div>
                        <div ref={ref}>
                            <div className="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle}>
                                <i id="toggle-button" className={isMenuOpen ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                            </div>
                            {isMenuOpen && (
                                <div className={isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu visible" : "nav-menu"}>
                                    <ul className="main-menu">

                                        <li><Link href="/" onClick={toggle}><a>Home</a></Link></li>
                                        <li><Link href="/blog" onClick={toggle}><a>Blog</a></Link></li>
                                        <li className="drp">
                                            <p className="dropbtn">Find <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></p>
                                            <ul className="dropdown-content">
                                                <li><Link href="/find/portable-keyboards" onClick={toggle}><a>Portable Keyboards</a></Link></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                     

                                    </ul>
                                
                                </div>
                            )}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </header>

        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next.js is a server-side rendering framework which means the initial call to generate HTML from the server. At this point, `window` object, is only available on the client-side (not on the server-side).

To solve this problem, you need to check `window` object availability.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";


const Navbar = () => {
    
    const isMobile = typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerWidth <= 767.98
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(!isMobile);
    const toggle = () => isMobile && setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        
        if (isMobile) {
          const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
            if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
              setIsMenuOpen(false);
            }
          };
        
          document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
        
          return () => {
            // Cleanup the event listener
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
          };
        }
      }, []);




    return (
        <>
            <header>

                <nav>
                    <div className="nav">

                        <div className="nav-brand">
                            <Link href="/" className="text-black"><a>Website</a></Link>
                        </div>
                        <div ref={ref}>
                            <div className="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle}>
                                <i id="toggle-button" className={isMenuOpen ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                            </div>
                            {isMenuOpen && (
                                <div className={isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu visible" : "nav-menu"}>
                                    <ul className="main-menu">

                                        <li><Link href="/" onClick={toggle}><a>Home</a></Link></li>
                                        <li><Link href="/blog" onClick={toggle}><a>Blog</a></Link></li>
                                        <li className="drp">
                                            <p className="dropbtn">Find <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></p>
                                            <ul className="dropdown-content">
                                                <li><Link href="/find/portable-keyboards" onClick={toggle}><a>Portable Keyboards</a></Link></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                     

                                    </ul>
                                
                                </div>
                            )}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </header>

        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Another way you can fix it is you can move that `window` logic into `useEffect` (or `componentDidMount` on a class-based component)

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";


const Navbar = () => {
    
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false); //the initial state depends on mobile-first or desktop-first strategy
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(true);
    const toggle = () => isMobile && setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 767.98)
      setIsMenuOpen(window.innerWidth > 767.98)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        
        if (isMobile) {
          const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
            if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
              setIsMenuOpen(false);
            }
          };
        
          document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
        
          return () => {
            // Cleanup the event listener
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
          };
        }
      }, [isMobile]);




    return (
        <>
            <header>

                <nav>
                    <div className="nav">

                        <div className="nav-brand">
                            <Link href="/" className="text-black"><a>Website</a></Link>
                        </div>
                        <div ref={ref}>
                            <div className="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle}>
                                <i id="toggle-button" className={isMenuOpen ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                            </div>
                            {isMenuOpen && (
                                <div className={isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu visible" : "nav-menu"}>
                                    <ul className="main-menu">

                                        <li><Link href="/" onClick={toggle}><a>Home</a></Link></li>
                                        <li><Link href="/blog" onClick={toggle}><a>Blog</a></Link></li>
                                        <li className="drp">
                                            <p className="dropbtn">Find <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></p>
                                            <ul className="dropdown-content">
                                                <li><Link href="/find/portable-keyboards" onClick={toggle}><a>Portable Keyboards</a></Link></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                     

                                    </ul>
                                
                                </div>
                            )}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </header>

        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Note that, with this solution, your UI may have some flickering due to `isMobile` state

Answer (score 0):

You should access browser APIs like `window` only inside `useEffect`, event handlers.... That's because your code gets executed first on the `server`.

`typeof window !== "undefined"`  is a hack that's not recommended, as it will most likely cause a [hydration error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error).

You could refactor your code this way:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  let [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(null);
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 767.98);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
      if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsMenuOpen(false);
      }
    };

    const checkWindowWidth = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 767.98);
    };
    if (isMobile) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", checkWindowWidth);

    return () => {
      // Cleanup the event listener
      window.removeEventListener("resize", checkWindowWidth);
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };
  }, [isMobile]);

  if(!isMobil === null) return null;

  return <>...</>;
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on your parent component definition.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Navbar = dynamic(() => import('./Navbar'), { ssr: false });

const Parent = () => {
  ...
  return (
     {(typeof window !== 'undefined') &&
     <Navbar/>
     }
     ...
     <Footer/>
  );
}
```

Comment: It solved my issue where I am using Neo4j. Thanks.