# Next.js "ReferenceError: window is not defined" with gapi-script

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-api-js-client

I've tried every work around, however, for some reason I keep getting the error in the screenshot below... not sure why?

> Server Error
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
> Call Stack
> eval
> node_modules/gapi-script/gapiScript.js (1:9)
> ./node_modules/gapi-script/gapiScript.js
> file:[...]/.next/server/pages/[...]/[id].js (98:1)
> **webpack_require**
> file:/[...]/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../../../styles/Home.module.css';
import { GoogleLoginButton } from '../../../components';
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';

export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/...`,
  );
  const data = await res.json();

  return { props: { data } };
}

const GAPI_CONFIG = {
  apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  scope: process.env.GOOGLE_SCOPE,
};

export default function NblOneTeam({ data }: any) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function start() {
      gapi.client.init(GAPI_CONFIG);
    }
    gapi.load('client:auth2', start);
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>NBL1 Scout Generator</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1>Hi NBL1 Teams</h1>
        <GoogleLoginButton />
        {data.map((player: any) => {
          return <h2>{player.name}</h2>;
        })}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As I mentioned, I've tried following work arounds like the following:
[Window is not defined in nextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548926/window-is-not-defined-in-nextjs)

Answer (score 2):

NextJs builds the pages server-side and window can only be accessed on the client-side. When the page loads window is always undefined in NextJs

The work around is importing gapi dynamically

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function start() {
     const gapi = (await import('gapi-script')).default
      gapi.client.init(GAPI_CONFIG);
    }
    gapi.load('client:auth2', start);
}, []);
```